# ASP.NET MVC 5 Html.DropDownListFor with datetime doesn't work SelectList selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a property with type Datetime and in the edit view the user select this property with a `Html.DropDownListFor` , the problem is that the `Html.DropDownListFor` doesn't get the property `Selected` in `SelectList` to select the value. I know that is because the value in the property has other value, but I works when I change the attribute name:

Values:

```
CancellationDate = {9/10/2016 12:00:00 AM}
CancellationDateListItem = new List<SelectListItem> {
   new SelectListItem 
                { 
                    Selected = true,
                    Text = "09/10/2016",
                    Value = "09/10/2016",
                    Disabled = false,
                    Group = null
                },
   new SelectListItem 
                { 
                    Selected = true,
                    Text = "09/11/2016",
                    Value = "09/11/2016",
                    Disabled = false,
                    Group = null
                }
};

CancellationDateListSelected = new SelectList(CancellationDateListItem);   

CancellationDateListWithStringSelectedValue = new SelectList(CancellationDateListItem, CancellationDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

CancellationDateListWithDateTimeSelectedValue = new SelectList(CancellationDateListItem, CancellationDate);
```

these examples doen't work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CancellationDate, CancellationDateListSelected )

@Html.DropDownList("CancellationDate", CancellationDateListSelected )

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CancellationDate, CancellationDateListWithStringSelectedValue )

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CancellationDate, CancellationDateListWithDateTimeSelectedValue )
```

but obviously this work fine:

```
@Html.DropDownList("OtherName", CancellationDateListWithStringSelectedValue )
```

I suppose/know this is by the DateTime type. Can I force in DropDownListFor to get the property `Selected` in `SelectList` to select the option?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be helpful. The reason it doesn't bind the value is - you are calling new on the item like below, all while setting the values.

```
  new SelectListItem 
    { 
        ....
    };
```

Instead, try using {get; set;} within your class definition. Then, in your controller, or else where in the implementaion, set the desired values.

```
  DateTime dt {get;set;}
  ...

  dt = "9/10/2015";
```

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is pointless when binding to a property because its the value of the property which determines the selected value. Since the value of `CancellationDate` is "9/10/2016 12:00:00 AM" which does not match any of the values in your select list (which are "09/10/2016" and "09/1/2016"), then the first option will always be selected (because something has to be).

Your GET method should include

```
List<string> dates = new List<string>() { "09/10/2016", "09/11/2016" };
model.CancellationDateListItem = new SelectList(dates);
model.CancellationDate = "09/11/2016";
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.CancellationDate, Model.CancellationDateListItem)
```

Because the value of `CancellationDate` matches the value of the second option, that value will be selected.

Comment: Ok, but Can I force in DropDownListFor to get the property Selected in SelectList to select the option?

Comment: No, because its the value of `CancellationDate` which determines what is selected (the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored) - that's how model binding works. The reason that `@Html.DropDownList("OtherName", Model.CancellationDateListItem)` would work is because your not binding to a property of your model.